# Tree Recursive Fibonacci Algorithm Requires Linear Space?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, language-agnostic, automation

I know that the Fibonacci series grows exponentially, therefore a recursive algorithm has a required number of steps that grow exponentially, however SICP v2 says that a tree recursive Fibonacci algorithm requires linear space because we only need to keep track of the nodes above us in the tree.

I understand that the required number of steps grows linear with Fib(n) but I would also assume that because the tree is expanding exponentially, the memory required in this event would need to be exponential as well. Can someone explain why the memory required only expands linearly to N, and not exponentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not store the whole tree but only as many stack frames as is the current depth you are in.

Answer (score 7):

I am guessing this is a consequence of the use of applicative order in evaluation. Given

```
(define (fib n)
(cond ((= n 0) 0) ((= n 1) 1) (else (+ fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
```

[from *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*]

normal-order evaluation of (fib 5) would keep expanding until it got to primitive expressions:

```
(+ (+ (+ (+ (fib 1) (fib 0)) (fib 1)) (+ (fib 1) (fib 0))) (+ (+ (fib 1) (fib 0) (fib 0)))
```

That would result in all the leaves of the tree being stored in memory, which would require space space exponentially related to n.

But applicative-order evaluation should proceed differently, driving down to primitive expressions along one branch to two leaves, and then ascending the branch and accumulating any side branches. This would result in a maximum length expression for (fib 5) of:

```
(+ (+ (+ (+ (fib 1) (fib 0)) (fib 1)) (fib 2)) (fib 3))
```

This expression is much shorter than the expression used in normal-order evaluation. The length of this expression is not affected by the number of leaves in the tree, only the depth of the tree.

This is my answer after staring at that sentence in SICP for more time than I care to admit.

Comment: "staring at that sentence in SICP for more time than I care to admit." wish the authors had explained as clearly. It is certainly not obvious.

Answer (score -1):

the difference between the normal-order evaluation and applicative-order evaluation is similar to the difference between depth first search algorithm and breadth first search algorithm algorithm.

In this cause, it is a normal-order evaluation, all the  combinations as arguments would be evaluated one by one until there is no combination anymore by the order from left to right(when combination being is evaluating, if there are still combinations inside the the combination being evaluating, the first one of these combinations would be evaluating right after in the next evaluation, and go on like this.), 
which means the space would first expanse and then shrink, when the first combination got evaluate.

And go on like this, the second, the third. Making the max space for the whole evaluation depend on the depth of the evaluation proceess.

Hence a tree recursive Fibonacci algorithm requires linear space.hope it would help